# Determine Android version

Tags: android

I have bought a 7'' pad from a chineese supplier, claiming that it is a 'Android 2.0'. But in the settings menu I read this:

Firmware version: 1.6
Kernel version: 2.6.29-00236-g48dbbb-dirty
Build number: WMT2.1.2_105

The supplier points at the build number, claiming that this is the 'Android version'. What is the significance of 'build number', anything to do with the 'Android version', or unrelated?
And, what is really my 'Android version'?

Comment: If that's something from China, you better thanks for that it is REALLY running on Android.

Comment: Perhaps this question is better for http://superuser.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `Firmware version` is the pre android 2.0 name for the `Android Version`.  So from your supplied info I think you have a 1.6 device.  Here are the [steps](http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=189189)

Comment: Great thanks, that was a very effective way to prove my point to the supplier...

Answer (score 0):

The "Firmware version" is the "Android version". In fact, Android even changed the text from "Firmware version" to "Android version" in the sources, perhaps to avoid this confusion.

The firmware/android version changes with each big new release.
The build number is something which increases with minor changes.

From the strings.xml file for the Settings application:

```
<string name="firmware_version">Android version</string>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment on the build number. This is what I expected but neede confirmed.